# In what file are scripts/pictures/stylesheets loaded on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change everything to load from http to https. The problem is that I can't find in what file or files does wordpress load this stuff.

Does anybody know?

Comment: So you want to redirect all traffic from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`

Comment: No. I want everything that is loaded via http such as scripts, stylesheets, images to be loaded via https instead.

Comment: This may be helpful for you: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-http-to-https-links